# sharepoint webparts, Swap image on click

Tags: image, sharepoint, click, web-parts, swap

I'm working on sharepoint project, i have like 1000 image i want to upload, i need webpart or something to do swap images on click, is there any web part that do this?
what the best method to use on my situation.

Comment: Is this like an image gallary (like flickr) or something else? You're going to have to provide some more details of what you're trying to do to get good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you a SharePoint developer? If not, I'd strongly suggest not even trying to do this. Modifying SharePoint beyond out-of-the-box options requires some extensive asp.net and SharePoint-centric developer skills. Even then, it's not a joy to work with.

In the past, for modifying UI interactions, I found the saner approach is to manipulate the DOM post-render. Load up jQuery and then upon page render, do your thing.